# Populating a gridview column with an object list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview of messages that is populated by an object class. There is a list in the object so that for each message, there is a list of recipients. Problem is, right now the gridview is only displaying "Person[]" for each message. I want it to display as a count of the recipients in the list.

Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
    <asp:GridView
        ID="grdMsgSent"
        runat="server"
        CssClass="cellSpacing"
        OnRowDataBound="grdMsgSent_RowDataBound"
        AllowSorting="True"
        EmptyDataText="You have not sent any messages."
        AllowPaging="True"
        PageSize="6"
        OnPageIndexChanging="grdMsgSent_PageIndexChanging"
        OnSorting="grdMsgSent_Sorting"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>

<asp:BoundField DataField="Recipients" HeaderText="Recipients" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

C#

```
grdMsgSent.DataSource = listSentMsg.List;
            grdMsgSent.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you have a data column name called `UserID`, you can populate in grid view using Eval (DataBinding Expression). So your code will be like this in aspx page,

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserID" Visible="false">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblUserID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

In C# Code Behind,

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dataColumn;
        dataColumn = new DataColumn("UserID");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a templatefield:

For array[], do this:

```
<Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>                        
            <asp:Label ID="Label1"  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Recipients.Length") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

For List, do this:

```
<Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>                        
            <asp:Label ID="Label1"  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Recipients.Count") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Adding the Eval, I am still getting the "Service.Person[]" in the recipients column. I know that it isn't an empty array though, because I used the service client to view the list populating with the correct data.

Comment: You have to do like: `Eval("YourArray.Count") `.

Comment: I'm getting an error message telling me that my array does not contain a property with the name 'Count'.

Comment: Solved it with this: <%#String.Join(",",((Message)Container.DataItem).Recipients.Count()) %>